# Add a "Split button" in collapsible-set (JQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there are any way to add the split button (that comes with ListView) to the collapsible; I have tried/tested the below code, but doesn't work!

```
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="e"  data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="e">

<div data-role="collapsible">      

<h3> Breakfast </h3>

<p>
<a href="somthing.html"> the contents comes here. 
</a>
</p>

<a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
split button 2
</a>
</div>


<div data-role="collapsible">      

<h3> Lunch</h3>

<p>
<a href="somthingElse.html"> the contents comes here. 
</a>
</p>

<a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
split button 2
</a>
</div>


</div>
```

**Any Idea or any other solution (workaround) is highly welcome.**

Comment: Can you share a picture of split button (that comes with ListView) because I don't understand what do you relay want to do?

Comment: I also tried to add href icon inside <h3> as below:
    <h3> Breakfast <a href='ff.html'> <img src=dd /> </a></h3>
But I cann't click on the icon/image, and it come very close to the text Not as the split button that come on the opposite edge/side.

Comment: Gajotres, the picture is gear (data-split-icon="gear")

Comment: So you want the gear image instead of the plus / minus images on the collapsible icon? I've added a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPhJp/ could you explain more please?

Comment: No, Mr.Phill, I need two icons, one one the left another on right.  As "Split button" on Listview.

Comment: @BasharAbuShamaa so just so I understand, where the word Lunch is, you want this a button? and also have the collapsible  as well. Correct?

Comment: Yes Phill, please read my comment (scond second)

Comment: see this link may help you: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-split.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it needs a little work but here is what I have

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/yPhJp/5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/yPhJp/6/ ( Adding verbiage to the collapsible )

JS

```
$(".splitButtonClicked").on("click", function (event, ui) {
    alert('Hello');
    return false; // stop collapsible event
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
                        <li><a href="#">
                            <h3>Breakfast</h3>
                        </a><a href="#breakfast_menu" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="splitButtonClicked">View Menu</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h2>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
                        <li><a href="#">
                            <h3>Lunch</h3>
                        </a><a href="#lunch_menu" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="splitButtonClicked">View Menu</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Phill, I hope to help me in format the split icon, it is not fit.